# Running 32-bit ARM code on Docker Desktop for Mac without emulation

Tags: docker

I am running a native `arm64` Debian container on my Apple Silicon Mac under Docker Desktop. In order to run 32-bit `armhf` processes on this container, I also ran:

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt install -y libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
```

However, even when I run 32-bit binaries, they appear to get started under QEMU user space emulation:

```
root@65ff75105398:~# ps -awx
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
  407 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/qemu-arm /opt/some/armhf-thing
```

I cannot access `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` even when running in privileged mode to disable this.

Is there another way I can get these `armhf` executables running without emulation?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: I have not, sorry. I imagine you would have to modify the virtual machine in which Docker Desktop for Mac runs its containers, but I don't know how to do that.